# variable in header location doesnt work in iframe?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi guys i am doing a personal project which i want to use on my small business, i am not that rich thats why i cant afford to hire a developer to do it for me :( my problem is that variable seems not to work if its called on an iframe, ok just like i said im not a pro developer so even on terms im not sure what to use so i will just explain on whatever i can and i hope some one can catch up with me.

an iframe is called on uikit modal, url on iframe have parameters
[image]
file is called firstreminder.php and this is the code

```
<?php
require_once 'layout/header.php';

if(!empty($_GET['message'])){
    $sms_msg = 'https://www.experttexting.com/ExptRestApi/sms/json/Message/Send?username=xpertdotmedia&password=c61iQO1E&api_key=4aw0l0noipli133&from=LocalVerify&to=63'.urlencode($_GET['mobile']).'&text=' . urlencode($_GET['message']) . '&type=text';

    $msg_json = file_get_contents($sms_msg);
    $msg_array = json_decode($msg_json, true);
}
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
    $clientid = $query['userid'];
    $getinvid = $query['invid'];
?>

<form action="">
    <div class="uk-margin">
    <textarea rows="6" cols="50" name="message" class="uk-textarea"/><?php
echo 'Greetings,
Just a friendly reminder for your upcoming due on '.$query['date'].'
Thank you
*auto msg do not reply';    
?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin">
    <?php echo '<input type="text" name="mobile" class="uk-input" value="'.$query['userphone'].'" />';?>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin">
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="submit">Send</button> 
    </div>
    <?php
    if(!empty($msg_array)){
        $status = $msg_array['Status'];
        if($status!="1"){
            header('Location: sent.php?id='.$getinvid);
        }
    }
    ?>
</form>
<?php
require_once 'layout/footer.php';
?>
```

so far its working good as i can fetch value of each parameters, example i can call `$query['date']`whenever i want and its actually working but problem lies on header location as it doesnt seem to fetch the value of the variable, header location is called whenever the script successfully sent the sms message and then it redirect to sent.php as i want to remind the user that sms was successfully sent and also update the database and this is the code of the sent.php file

```
<?php
require_once 'layout/header.php';
$senturl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$invURL = parse_url($senturl);
parse_str($invURL['query'], $smsquery);
$invoID = $smsquery['id'];
$updateSentTo = "UPDATE ffcko_invoices_invoices SET last_sent=NOW() WHERE ffcko_invoices_invoices.id=$invoID;";

if (mysqli_query($DBcon, $updateSentTo)) {
    echo '<h1 class="uk-h3 uk-text-success">Message Sent <span uk-icon="icon: check; ratio: 1.5"></span></h1>';
    echo '<script>window.top.location.reload();</script>';
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $updateSentTo . "<br>" . mysqli_error($DBcon);
}
mysqli_close($DBcon);

require_once 'layout/footer.php';
?>
```

it should go to sent.php?id=(id) so that i can successfully update the database but i always end up with this error
[image]

i tried all the combinations i can, i even transfered the code from sent.php to firstreminder.php inorder for it to have a direct control of the variable but still problem occurs as if the `$getinvid` is being ignored

i think it has something to do with the iframe? you think so? cause if I enter the url directly to my browser

http://localhost/sms/sent.php?id=3

adding the id manually it works as it should and it updates the database so i wonder what im doing wrong?

hope you guys can help me, thank you so much and i hope i have explained it well as english is not my native language so i really really apologize.

Comment: Why aren't you just using `$_GET['id']`? Why all the `parse_str` / `parse_url` nonsense?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You don't need to reinvent the wheel with parsing the url. In php the superglobals $[_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and $[_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) contain the query string parameters and data POST-ed to the script.

Comment: @ceejayoz like i said im not a professional programmer i built the script from numerous sources so when i see it works i am already satisfied :) thank you for your input ill do more reasearch about that

Comment: @tadman this script is for personal use and be use by me only so whatever works easy i stick i never had the time to play more and i am afraid making the script secure is hard for me to understand and will take so much time for me to accomplish whatever i want, does sql injection really matter if i just use it on my localhost and personal use? i dont have that much time to do reasearch more but if you insist and think i really need it i might do thank you

Comment: @peter ramanyi ok sorry but i wasnt aware of that lol i will check your suggestion and see if i can make it work thank you

Comment: @cryptohustla Hey, no need to apologize for not knowing something. We are all here to learn.

Comment: @cryptohustla If you're trying to learn PHP, learn how to write SQL queries properly. If you continue to do it this way you'll eventually end up in trouble, these are really bad habits to get into. Using parameterized queries makes your code easier to understand and harder to get wrong, two things really valuable when learning.

Comment: thanks @PeterRakmanyi

Comment: @tadman i undersand what you are tryin to say again its just for personal purpose i dont want to make it hard for me lol but yeah just incase i want to do it on a serious project i really need some serious strategy of implementing good practice thank you

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding here. Doing it the right way is the easier way: Less time spent with fussy syntax bugs, less time trying to figure out why the query "doesn't work", and code that's easier to look at and understand. `mysqli` requires an extra line of code or two, plus PDO is actually a lot more friendly, even less work to use correctly, so it's worth using if you can make the switch.